# how to encourage custom commands to adopt the math font

Tags: fonts, math-mode

When defining new commands or math operators, I have trouble convincing the operator to adopt the ambient math font instead of the default CM font.  I observed that if I use the `mathdesign` package, then the operators do my bidding, but I want to use `eulervm` or other packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eulervm} % eulervm for math 
\usepackage{bera} % bitstream font for text
\newcommand{\tot}{\mathrm{tot}}

\begin{document}
This text is bitstream, ``X'' below is eulervm. Problem: ``tot'' is CM.
\[
    f: X \to \tot(L) 
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> Function names as well as math accents are taken from the default text
>   font family. This holds for the math alphabets `\mathrm` and `\mathbf`,
>   too. The `eulervm` package determines the default font family (i.e., the
>   meaning of the macro `\familydefault`) at load time and will apply it
>   for the above purposes then. In the same way, the math alphabets
>   `\mathsf` and `\mathtt` are mapped to `\sfdefault` and `\ttdefault`. Thus, you
>   should redefine the default text fonts before loading the `eulervm`
>   package!

Which means that `\mathrm` etc will use the textfont families. So if you want eulervm you should either use the chars directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bera} % bitstream font for text
\usepackage{eulervm} % eulervm for math
\newcommand{\tot}{\mathrm{bitstream}}
\newcommand{\tat}{\mathsf{sffamily}}
\newcommand{\tit}{\mathtt{ttfamily}}
\begin{document}
This text is bitstream, ``X'' below is eulervm. Problem: ``tot'' is CM.
\textsf{sffamily}, \texttt{ttfamily}

\[
    f: X \to eulervm, \tot, \tat,  \tit 
\]
\end{document}
```

Or define/redefine your own math alpabeth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bera} % bitstream font for text
\usepackage{eulervm} % eulervm for math
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\matheuler}  {U}{zeur}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
This text is bitstream, ``X'' below is eulervm. 

\[
    f: X \to \matheuler{eulervm}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `eulervm` (math) **after** `bera` (text).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bera} % bitstream font for text
\usepackage{eulervm} % eulervm for math 
\newcommand{\tot}{\mathrm{tot}}

\begin{document}
This text is bitstream, ``X'' below is eulervm. Problem: ``tot'' is CM.
\[
    f: X \to \tot(L) 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution puts "tot" in bera, not eulervm.  Since it is defined using \mathrm, I would expect it to use the math font...

Comment: @mgualt: Well, LaTeX usually uses text font for `\mathrm`, `\mathsf` and `\mathtt` by default. This is also what other font packages do. Personally, Euler fonts are not very good for `\mathrm`, the `\mathnormal` and `\mathrm` should differ. And of courcse you can redefine `\mathrm` using `\DeclareMathAlphabet` or `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet` if you wish.